# How to calculate errors/confidence intervals of parameters from least squares fitting which have high correlation

Tags: correlation, covariance, error

I'm no statistician but I want to be more honest about my error bars. Let's say I have a dataset which is described by some model $f(x,{params})$ where ${params}$ is a vector of many parameters for which I'm fitting. Unfortunately my parameters are highly correlated, but because I have thousands of datapoints, the variances, standard errors, and other common error estimations are small. But if I know the covariances between all params $p_1$ through $p_n$, then how can I be more honest in calculating my errors or confidence intervals?

Below is an extreme example of my problem in which I have a dataset described by $y=2x$, but I'm fitting it with a model $y=(a/b)x$. $a$ and $b$ are obviously not identifiable and so any values of them which give a ratio of 2 will minimize the error. However the variances and all errors calculated from it are infinitesimal. How can I use the covariances to say something more meaningful about the error estimates?

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

What's being reported as your standard errors are on the order of [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon), the error introduced by computers' floating point arithmetic due to rounding (for decimal 64)! They almost certainly reflect errors in the way *floating point calculations are made on the computer*. From a computational perspective of adding or subtracting numbers near 1, they are indistinguishable from zero.

I suspect you did something like:

- `x = randn(100, 1)` then
- `y= 2 * x`
- then regressed `y` on `x`.

When I do that, my stats code reports a standard error of `4.1139e-16`. But that probably isn't my *actual* standard error! If floating point were infinitely precise, the number should be 0, but [floating point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) isn't that precise! Rather, I'm getting 0 + some tiny, meaningless garbage value due to floating point imprecision.

#### Some floating point arithmetic examples:

For example, try to calculate on a computer: `(1 + 2) / 3 - 1/3 - 2/3`

The result should be 0, right? Except you'll probably get something like 1e-16.

Another thing to try:
$$ 1 + 10^{-17} - 1$$
Should be $10^{-17}$ right? Nope! It's precisely 0 under IEEE-754 double precision floating point arithmetic because $1 + 10^{-17} = 1$ due to rounding!

Answer (score 0):

The [GUM](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiwudalt_3OAhUCQBoKHWU_D8QQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bipm.org%2Futils%2Fcommon%2Fdocuments%2Fjcgm%2FJCGM_100_2008_E.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGlX6kEcxhxK1MQiIdUuTX_QnIPVw&cad=rja) (Guide to the expression of uncertainty in measurement) states on page 33 about "correlated input quantities":

> When the input quantities are correlated, the appropriate expression
>   for the combined variance u^2_c ( y) associated with the result of a
>   measurement is: [image: equation]

The square-root of this should be the standard uncertainty you were asking for.
You'll need the sensitivity of the model for each coefficient (=derivatives), however.
Hope this helps?